# accessing serverside code from client program

Tags: asp.net

How can I access server side functions from the HTML code? See the following code:

```
<a id="Taggloud" runat="server" class="lblTagCloud" onClick="TagOnCloud_Click">click</a>
```

Here I'm calling the `tagonCloud_click` function that's defined in server side(code behind). How can i call that function?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a full post back, swap out the `<a>` tag for a `<asp:HyperLink>`, which will allow you to wire up server-side event handlers.

Comment: Actually it's just necessary to add Runat="server" to convert it Server Side Control , not <asp: ....

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a web service and call that web service from the client (via jQuery is one option).

That web service can call a function.  However, I'd put the code you have in the tagonCloud_click function in another function and have the click call that function.  That way both the web service and click function can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LinkButton server side control:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Taggloud" runat="server" onclick="TagOnCloud_Click">click</asp:LinkButton>
```